# Hide some of the field in GridEditMode.PopUp mode

Tags: telerik-mvc

I have Telerik MVC Grid which has popup edit form with several fields on of them is `ID` field.

```
.Editable(editing => editing.Mode(GridEditMode.PopUp))
```

I would like to hide `ID` field from popup edit form, how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a view using *.ascx file , where you you will design the form as per the requirement  and you can provide template name in .Editable as shown below

.Editable(editing => editing.Mode(GridEditMode.PopUp)
            .TemplateName("MyView"))

Where MyView is a ascx file which holds the fields to be displayed.